# ChannelHandler is not a sharable Handler

Tags: java, netty

Alright so I am experimenting with Netty 4.0.19 (which is great by the way) and having one connection works fine, but once there are multiple connections there is an error that the handler is not a shared handler and cannot have multiple items.

This is my Handler class: [ChannelManager.java](https://github.com/limnic/rss/blob/master/src/org/rigid/net/ChannelManager.java)

I was thinking, maybe every connection needs its own handler, but then I'm not sure how I will implement that in my current environment. Any suggestions or ideas?

**EDIT :**
I wasn't sure how to ask this question on google... so excuse me if this question already exists.

I think it has something to do with line 59 in the code. I saw some use of a ChannelInitializer but I don't know how to use that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if your handler can be shared between multiple clients you need to annotate the class with:

```
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me.